# How does /proc/{pid}/stack work in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded system and testing out in ubuntu 18.04 . Now the embedded system doesn't have `/proc/{pid}/stack` implemented . So I am trying to implement the same using C ( if possible) or find out the API for the same. I tried reading `man` page for `/proc`. I tried reading the actual process stack using `process_vm_readv()` but that doesn't give the desired output. I can't use `ptrace` since that halts the running program. So I just want to 'snoop' on processes stack of another process preferably implement the same using C.

Any guidance on how `/proc/{pid}/stack` gets the data or if it uses some API.

Comment: What are you using `/proc/{pid}/stack` for? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: I am trying to make like a debugger program. Something which might give an idea of where program is on execution. Like let's say some program on embedded system is taking longer then usual, I would want to inspect the status of that program to maybe find the issue and debug in future.

Comment: Perhaps use [the `ptrace` call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) instead? Or why not use GDB to attach to the process you want to debug?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ptrace halts the running program, I tried with ptrace but faced this problem of halt. GDB uses Ptrace() only.